# Redux - Saga, put parent function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

There is a way to call a props function (which is passed by the parent component, not in the current component), in saga container after a specific request?

This is my example

***saga.js***

```
export function* getItem(options) {
    try {
        const url = `....`;
        const response = yield call(request, url);
        // here setResponse is an action that modify reducer and it's fine
        yield put(setResponse(response));
        // here I want to put a props parents function(something like this), but in sagas I dont't have access to props
        yield put(this.props.parentFunction)
    } catch (e) {
        .....
    }
}
```

The only way I found is to use a callback(so I call the props to function in ***index.js*** and exist) or pass directly the function as getItems ***options***.

There is a cleaner way?

Comment: What this `parentFunction` do? Why you need to run it only after saga completes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your goal, but I've faced a similar challenge -

> I need to run this function after my saga completes.

Usually it's presentation or component-related (e.g. hide a spinner). `Redux-Form`, for example, takes a Promise-creating `submit` handler. How do we transform a saga call into a promise?

So like you've suggested, we could pass the function around. OR, we could go the other direction -- "how can my component subscribe to redux events?"

You can definitely hack something together that works for your use-case, but I use [redux-saga-thunk](https://github.com/diegohaz/redux-saga-thunk) for this. It allows saga-running action dispatch calls to return a promise: `this.props.runSaga().then(...`

As a bonus, you also get "derived state" selectors like `pending(ACTION_NAME)`, which is very handy for showing loading UI without manually managing boolean flags.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming `parentFunction` is pure.** You can achieve that by passing `parentProps` as an argument in addition to `options` to your action. Here is the pattern:

Here, `getItemsAction` gets 2 arguments:

- options: some data
- parentProps: props from parent component

```
export const function getItemsAction(options, parentProps){
    return ({ type: GET_ITEMS_REQUEST, payload: {options , parentProps} });
}
```

By providing these parameters to the action, these will be available to you inside the saga (i.e options & parentProps):

```
export function* getItemsSaga({ ...payload }) {
    try {
        const url = `....`;
        const response = yield call(request, url);
        // here setResponse is an action that modify reducer and it's fine
        yield put(setResponse(response));
        // here I want to put a props parents function(something like this), but in sagas I dont't have access to props
        yield put(parentProps)
    } catch (e) {
        .....
    }
}
```

This way parentFunction can be stored in parentProps, and accessed within the saga.